# How to cache data for a certain period of time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets, caching

In my code, I'm parsing a google sheets, and I don't want to run into a limit. How can I implement caching in node js so that it asks for data from the table no more than once every few minutes?

Comment: Is RAM size an issue here? If not, then just put data into a variable or database and refresh it N minutes later.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant parts of the code you're working on?

Answer (score 0):

Store data along with a timestamp. If that timestamp is past a certain timespan, say 5 minutes, when a request is made, refetch it. If it's within that timespan, just return the cached data.

```
if (cache["document_name"].timestamp + 5*60 < Date.now())
    return cache["document_name"].data;
else
    return fetchData();
```